# Show this two variable homogeneous function grows according to the power law.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I have a two variable function $g(x,F)$ which maps to $\mathbb{R} \geqslant0$. $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. $g$ is such that:

for any scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$,$\quad$ $g(\lambda x,\lambda F)=\lambda g(x,F)$, where $\lambda F=\{\lambda x\in \mathbb{R}^n  \quad | \quad x \in F\}$.

I must show that, for fixed $F$, $g(x,F) \sim \frac{c}{x^\alpha}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ for some $c > 0 ,\alpha \geqslant0$.

Other properties of $g$, which may be useful (although I am unsure if they are at all required) are:

.For any fixed $F$, $g$ is non-increasing as $x$ increases.

.If $E \subset F$ then $g(x,E) \leqslant g(x,F)\quad \forall x$

Edit: It may be the case that in fact $g(x,F) = \frac{c}{x^\alpha}$ and not just $g(x,F) \sim \frac{c}{x^\alpha}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Sorry. I muddled up a couple of functions I was working on. I will edit to correct the mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.